# Use SELECT_TAGS in properties drawer to selectively export subheadings

Tags: org-mode, exporting

When you only want to export subtees with a specific tag - for example "special" -  you can use `#+SELECT_TAGS: special`

What is the correct synthax to use this functionality in a property drawer, so the setting ist just for one Subtree?

What didn't work for me was:

```
* Heading1
:PROPERTIES:
:SELECT_TAGS: special
:END:
** Subheading 1.1
** Subheading 1.2 :special:

* Heading2
** Subheading 2.1
** Subheading 2.2 :special:
```

The Goal is to only export "Subheading 1.2" because it has the `special` Tag and is child of "Heading 1", but not "Subheading 2.2" which also has the `special` Tag.

Comment: The documentation states: " When exporting sub-trees, special node properties can override the
above keywords.  These properties have an ‘EXPORT_’ prefix.  For
example, ‘DATE’ becomes, ‘EXPORT_DATE’ when used for a specific
sub-tree.  Except for ‘SETUPFILE’, all other keywords listed above have
an ‘EXPORT_’ equivalent", so having a subtree property `EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS` *should* work - but my attempts to make it work have so far been futile.

However, even if you can make that work, that still would not accomplish what you want.

Comment: You probably would have to add a (global) `#+EXCLUDE_TAGS` and tag each unwanted (sub)tree with the excluded tag.